# Way to find who earned a specific hat on a specific site

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Let's say I want to figure out which users on [site X] earned [hat Y]. I can, of course, go through and examine each hatted user to see what hat(s) they have. On most sites, however, this is incredibly tedious.

I would like to have a search functionality of some sort, that I can use to figure this out, e.g. in the Leaderboard of Winterbash.

Comment: There is such a thing for badges on sites. A similar search functionality for hats could be nice (a list of all hats on site X, with the number of users who earned them). That said, I think part of the fun might be to come across the hats just by seeing users wear them.