# Who else has this hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Can we get a list of people who have a certain hat?

Or at least to know their number, how many people have it?

I've got Sherlock (yay!), and I want to know how rare it is.

Even better if there was a way to have a list of hats in order of their rarity - either on a specific site, like Stackoverflow, or the entire network. Is there such a way?

Comment: I did request this [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271005/274942). I'm in still in favor, though it's not a hugely important added functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Even better if there was a way to have a list of hats in order of their rarity - either on a specific site, like Stackoverflow, or the entire network. Is there such a way?

Not directly, but… sort of. The users' top hats on the site and network leaderboards are ordered by rarity.

If you look at the [network-wide leaderboard](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) right now, for example, you can see that (over the whole network) *Sherlock* is rarer than *Silencium*, but *The Milliner* is even rarer:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When Winter Bash is over, I'm sure we'll see a blog post [much like last year's](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/09/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/), giving the statistics on which hats were rarest, etc.

I do not know if there is a way to check who has which hats *during* Winter Bash.

You can learn how hard they are to get (except for the secret hats) here: https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com